# AngularJS pagination and after change page call post to server, double request

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I add pagination to my website:

```
<pagination
    ng-model="currentPage"
    total-items="printResult.pg"
    max-size="printResult.pg"
    boundary-links="true">
  </pagination>

 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="offer in printResult.offers">

      <p>{{offer.name}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Now when user click another page, script should call post request to server. It works, but performs twice and not once. In firebug I can see, there are two request to the server, should be one.

```
angular.module('PostService', [])
  .controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope, PostModel) {

    var srv = this;
    srv.offers = [];
    var urlFromForm = '';
 $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function() {

      if(urlFromForm.url) {
        console.log("Klikam + " + $scope.currentPage);
        console.log("Url:  " + urlFromForm.url);

        pageNumber = $scope.currentPage;
        postUrlToService(urlFromForm);
      }
    });

    function postUrlToService(url) {

      $scope.dataLoading = true;
      $scope.printResult = null;
      urlFromForm = url;
      initCreate();
      PostModel.postUrl(url).then(function (result) {
        srv.offers = result.data;
        $scope.totalItems = srv.offers.pg;
        $scope.printResult = srv.offers;
        $scope.dataLoading = false;
      });
    }

    function initCreate() {
      srv.newUrl = {url: ''};
    }

    srv.postUrlToService = postUrlToService;

  })
  .constant('ENDPOINT', 'http://localhost:8080/api/send')
  .service('PostModel', function ($http, ENDPOINT) {

    var service = this;

    function getUrl() {
      return ENDPOINT;
    }

    service.postUrl = function (url) {

      return $http.post(getUrl(), url);
    };
  });
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:

I got an error, my function `$scope.$watch` execute twice. When I click on the next page, captures its number, but once a number of the first page. The next page does not light up. All the time the button is lit 1 page.

Log:

```
WatchPage: 1
 Call postUrlToService [object Object]
Post: [object Object]
Server response: [object Object]
WatchPage: 2
Click + 2
Url:  http://exmaple.com/tring=&bmatch=s0-fas-1-4-0408
 Call postUrlToService [object Object]
Post: [object Object]
WatchPage: 1 //after response code set watchpage to 1, why? 
Server response: [object Object]
```

After response code set watchpage to 1, why? How to set page when user click?

EDIT

It works. All pages equals 100 but on link I have access to 10. Why?

```
 <pagination total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
              ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```

[image]

```
angular.module('PostService', [])
  .controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope, AllegroModel) {

    var srv = this;
    var urlFromForm = '';
    var pageNumber = '';

    var flag=0;
    srv.offers = [];

    $scope.totalItems = 0;

    $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;

    function postUrlToService(url) {

      $scope.dataLoading = true;
      $scope.printResult = null;
      urlFromForm = url;
      initCreate();

      console.log('Call postUrlToService ' + url);

      PageModel.postUrl(angular.extend({},
        {page: pageNumber},url)).then(function (result) {

        srv.offers = result.data;

        console.log('Server response: ' + srv.offers);

        if(flag==0) {
          $scope.totalItems = srv.offers.pg;
        }
        $scope.printResult = srv.offers;
        $scope.dataLoading = false;
        flag=1;
      });
    }

    function initCreate() {
      srv.newUrl = {url: ''};
    }

    $scope.$watch("currentPage", function(newInput, oldInput) {
      if(newInput != oldInput){
        //Do your stuff
        console.log(newInput);
        pageNumber = newInput;
        $scope.currentPage = newInput;
        postUrlToService(urlFromForm);
      }
    });

    srv.postUrlToService = postUrlToService;

  })
  .constant('ENDPOINT', 'http://localhost:8080/api/send')
  .service('PageModel', function ($http, ENDPOINT) {

    var service = this;

    function getUrl() {
      return ENDPOINT;
    }

    service.postUrl = function (url) {
      console.log("Post: " + url);
      return $http.post(getUrl(), url);
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function(newInput, oldInput) {
    if(newInput != oldInput){
        //Do your stuff
    }
});
```

Will fix your problem.

Comment: It works when if is empty. `console.log(newInput)` works fine. But when I add my function `postUrlToService(urlFromForm);` problem is the same...

Comment: Perhaps what happens is that the currentPage and numPerPage scopes are changed both, so a double trigger. Can you console.log both watchers seperately?

Comment: Ok, I do this and this works, but I have another problem. All pages equals 100 but on link I have access to 10.

Comment: When I go to 10 page, next button is block, I dont go to next page.

Comment: Are you sure that the pagination has more pages? Try to start at 9, click the next page button. It looks like there are no pages left after 10

Comment: Yes, because `totalItems` = 100. When I start at 9 I can click Next.

Comment: Tell me please what the output is from: printResult.pg

Comment: I don't use `printResult.pg` please check my updated question.

Comment: When I updated my question I replaced this to `totalItems`. Both values are 100

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110490/discussion-between-donny-van-v-and-lukassz).

Comment: Issue is fixed. Miss calculation